# Unable to extract images from a zip file

Tags: zip

I download the train2017.zip file of the 2017 COCO dataset (https://cocodataset.org/#download). The file only has a lot of .jpg images. I'm trying to unzip the file by

```
unzip train2017.zip
```

on my linux machine. After a few hundred files (out of thousands more) are extracted, all subsequent files do not get extracted because of an error:

```
error:  cannot create train2017/000000115077.jpg
    File too large
error:  cannot create train2017/000000408201.jpg
    File too large
error:  cannot create train2017/000000461561.jpg
    File too large
error:  cannot create train2017/000000511224.jpg
    File too large
error:  cannot create train2017/000000291833.jpg
    File too large
error:  cannot create train2017/000000010581.jpg
    File too large
error:  cannot create train2017/000000176314.jpg
    File too large
error:  cannot create train2017/000000076079.jpg
    File too large
error:  cannot create train2017/000000000839.jpg
    File too large
...
```

I don't understand why this is happening. All files are just .jpg images that shouldn't be too large. There is also more than enough space on my machine. I've downloaded and unzipped the file on several other linux systems successfully. I've never faced this before, and I'm not sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Output of dh-ih:

[image]

Comment: Check the i-nodes of filesystem

Comment: Haven't been using linux for a very long time, so I am not so sure what all the outputs of dh -ih means. But, some say 100%.

Comment: 100% free or used? BTW what is the filesystem you use (where you extract the images)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the answers to Romeo's questions. Also show us what you get when you run `df -ih`.

Comment: I've added a picture to the post, the location the files are being zipped to are on AFS.

Comment: Let's believe the error message "File too large", probably not the jpeg file size, but the zip file size. Maybe your `unzip` version is really old and can't deal with zip archives larger than 4 GB, so it fails after reaching that limit. Check the version (`unzip -v`). To get sure that your file system is not the problem, try `unzip -tq train2017.zip`

Comment: The version is "UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Debian. Original by Info-ZIP". The file itself seems to be fine too - "No errors detected in compressed data of train2017.zip".

Comment: @random_guest, seems like infozip have some limitations in number of files. Try to install `7zip` and extract the archive `7z x archive.zip`

Comment: Another thought: how much memory is on this system? Unzip & 7zip will need somewhere to write to in order to extract the images, & if the temporary files are not written to /tmp, they will be written to free memory -- which may be exhausted by the executable trying to extract hundreds of files.

Comment: I don't think I can install 7zip, I don't have sudo access.

Comment: @llywrch I think there is a memory issue. The maximum number of files is 31,706 exactly. I did some searching online and this seems to be an issue with the AFS filesystem. How do I switch to a different filesystem if I want a bigger file limit? The output of df -ih is in the post.

Comment: From a previous comment, you state you don't have sudo rights. Simplest (for you) is to explain the problem to your sysadmin & have him/her mount a different filesystem on this machine. Otherwise, you need to set up a non-AFS filesystem on a drive (say, a USB stick if you have one large enough), then mount that on the system--if you have mount rights--then move the files you want over. Good luck.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much